# What's difference between adding package from nuGet and from adding existing solution on workspace? (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms. (PCL Project)

I have experienced problems sometimes when I add package. 
Nomally, adding package from nuGet is fine.

Sometimes I add package by adding existing solution on workspace that cloned from github. 
Reason why I did this, because I can modify some code.

But somtimes it cause problem. 
I have used realm for Xamarin. 
and I added new other packages today. 
It causes this problem.
["Fody not properly installed" error exception. (Xamarin.forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409919/fody-not-properly-installed-error-exception-xamarin-forms)

But, I tried to add again from nuGet at this time. It works fine. What's difference between adding package from nuGet and from adding existing solution on workspace?

Comment: It is a bad idea to post duplicate questions if you only hit a single issue.

Comment: @LexLi OK. Got it.